# Install cross-compiler in debian

Tags: gcc, debian, cross-compiling

I am trying to install a cross-compiler in Debian, but I encountered the following error:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: command not found
```

When I try to install it:

```
 apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

It says unable to locate package gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf ([the tutorial I am following](https://community.freescale.com/docs/DOC-95017)).

Comment: gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf is currently only in sid (aka unstable). What version of debian do you have?

Comment: The debian version is Release 7.8 (wheezy) 32 bit, Kernel Linux 3.2.0-4-486

Comment: It seems crosscompiling is truly deceased starting with Debian 8.0. The Emdebian.org site says "no longer supported, just use regular Debian"  which points to wiki.debian.org. It in turn says "packages did not make it into jessie [i.e. 8.0]" and points back to emdebian.org. Really too bad, as it looked like Debian was making inroads in the embedded space (Raspbian etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian 9 already provides a collection of cross-compilers for various architectures, so following command is sufficient:

```
apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

Alternatively you can use [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/). With this project you'll be able to compile everything from toolchain till root file system.

Comment: If you are going to add `unstable`, you might as well install `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf` from the main repository, no need for emdebian.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid, emdebian doesn't have these sources anymore.

Comment: @ErikFriesen I could rewrite the answer to be compatible with upcoming Debian 9, that already ships a bunch of cross-compilers.