# compile gcc for armv7l from debian in linux

Tags: c, linux, armv7

I'm using GCC version 10.2.1  in Linux Debian (x86-64).
i write this c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("Hello World!");
  return 0;
}
```

Now my question is how can compile and run this code for **armv7l**
?
Target system Is a evaluation board
thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install cross-compiler in debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248539/install-cross-compiler-in-debian)

Comment: Do you try to compile with `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`, install it with `apt install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi`

Comment: i try this and now i want out put file and run file command in armv7l. can you help me pleas?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add which system you are targeting (we know the processor, armv7l). Is this a evaluation board? Which one? -- BTW, while you're at it, you could update your question and **add** the successful compilation, including what kind of executable you produced.

Comment: yes this is  evaluation board

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc hello.c -o hello` command . and befor you should install arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc in your linux system .

[here is full sample that work for me](https://www.acmesystems.it/arm9_toolchain)